# how to prevent innerHTML repeating the previous value

Tags: javascript

I'm a JS learner and want to create an app that will calculate the average from input values. So far I've managed to push the entered input values into an array. However, when I want to display them, the previous value is repeated. So I'm near the end. But now I'm stuck. Can you lend me hand with that?

```
        Enter
      </button>
      <p id="numbersEntered"></p>
      <button id="avg" type="button">Average</button>
      <p id="average"></p>
```

```
   let numbersEntered = document.querySelector("#numbersEntered");
   let inputEl = document.querySelector("#input");

   // buttons
   let enter = document.querySelector("#enter");

   let numArr = [];

   enter.addEventListener("click", displayNums);

   function displayNums() {
   let newNumber = inputEl.value;
   numArr.push(newNumber);
   console.log(numArr);

   for (let i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
    numbersEntered.innerHTML += numArr[i] + ",";
  }
  }
```

Comment: clear it before writing.

Comment: I really love it when advanced users downgrade my questions :).

Comment: @TomDev , Haha, there's a "be nice" policy in the act now. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just clear the innerHTML before appending;

```
function displayNums() {
   let newNumber = inputEl.value;
   numArr.push(newNumber);
   numbersEntered.innerHTML = "";  //Clear the innerHTML
   for (let i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
     numbersEntered.innerHTML += numArr[i] + ",";
   }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending `numArr` to innerHTML, simply overwrite it instead. Also, since you're only writing plain text, it is recommended to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`:

```
function displayNums() {
    let newNumber = inputEl.value;
    numArr.push(newNumber);
    console.log(numArr);

    numbersEntered.textContent = numArr.join(', ');
}
```

There is no need to use a `for` loop when you can use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to print the array out.

Comment: Thanks Terry, your solution also works, but there's a typo "numberedEntered' should be "numbersEntered". It's something new. I need to read about the .join method. It's quite intriguing.